# Firebase database detach listener

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I fetch live data like this:

```
//Firebase
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
var handle: FIRDatabaseHandle?

override func viewDidLoad() {

ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
handle = ref?.child("posts").child(String(itemId)).observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapShot) in
                        if let item = snapShot.value as? String {
                            print(item)
                        }
                    })

.....
```

Now reading the firebase docs I see this:

**Observers don't automatically stop syncing data when you leave a ViewController. If an observer isn't properly removed, it continues to sync data to local memory.**

So I added this function that gets fired when I exit the VC:

```
@IBAction func backButtonDidTouch(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let handle = handle {
                    ref?.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
                }
        showNavBar = true
        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

But I can also call `removeAllObservers()` insetad of `removeObserver()` and the docs also says:

**Calling `removeObserverWithHandle` or `removeAllObservers` on a listener does not automatically remove listeners registered on its child nodes; you must also keep track of those references or handles to remove them.**

So looking at my code am I doing it right? I dont want to keep data syncing between my app and firebase when I exit my VC

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be calling an observer on the specific post, but you are removing the observer from the parent reference. As the documentation states, removing a listener from a reference does not clear the observers from the children, hence I believe you have not removed the observer as you intended.

Comment: Should I use ``removeAllObservers`` instead?

Comment: Nope. You should simply call it on the location where you attached the listener: `ref?.child("posts").child(String(itemId)). removeObserverWithHandle...`

Comment: or if you are only getting the data once use the observeSingleEvent. Then you don't need to cancel it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this issue myself. Particularly when I log a user out, for a brief moment, the presenting view controller is trying to read from firebase and crashes. What I have done is define a set of type `DatabaseReference` among the singleton I am using. And where I call

```
ref.observe(.value) {(snapshot) in 
 singleton.refsUsed.insert(snapshot.ref)
 ...
}
```

Then upon logging out, before I dismiss the current view controller, I am iterating over all the items in the reference set and removing all observers.